# Quantum cohomology of projective bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

There is classical description of cohomology ring of projective bundle. Is there an analog in quantum cohomology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a quantum Leray-Hirsch Theorem, do to Maulik and Pandharipande [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412503).  It relates the Gromov-Witten theory of the projective line bundle to that of the base.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What about higher rank?

Comment: I haven't seen anything, but I stopped reading stuff in this area shortly after reading this paper.  I'd recommend emailing Maulik or Pandharipande, they would presumably know if it's been done for higher dimensional bundles.

Comment: @Charles Siegel  But do they provide the Quantum product?